# Does this kind of thing exist in the LaTeX habitat? Or is metaprogramming in order?

Tags: tables, matrices, csv, environment-variables, invoice

You know how matrices have coordinates like this:

[image]

Is there any way that I can import a `.csv` and then have automatically produced variables like `\a11` and `\a12`, etc.

Of course, unless there is an easier way to import a list of hours worked rows into LaTeX's `\usepackage{invoice}`.

I just want to be able to list each description/rate/count like this:

```
\begin{invoice}{Euro}{19}
   \ProjectTitle{Project A}%
       %    Contents                    Rate/Unit                     Count
       \Fee{\DescriptionFromRow1 i.e. \a21}     {\RateFromRow1 i.e. \a22}   {\CountFromRow1 i.e. \a23}
       \Fee{\DescriptionFromRow2 i.e. \a31}    {\RateFromRow2 i.e. \a32}   {\CountFromRow2 i.e. \a33}
\end{invoice}
```

Comment: This seems tedious. Know of a better way?

Comment: I think this might be easier with just passing my .csv file into an array in another program like Ruby and then generating a text file with LaTeX code that inserts my data in a for loop or something. Like metaprogramming...

Comment: Do you know any scripting language? I would personally go with AWK (nawk to be precise) to essentially write a small crude pre-processor which will convert cvs data into .tex source file which can be imported into the main tex document.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you want. It would be helpful if you posted the exact input and desired output and a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. Am pretty sure that this can be be done with some combination of `datatool`, `pgfplotstable`, `csvsimple` and perhaps the `collcell` package.

Comment: it doesn't help understand your question that `\a12` is not a valid command name, if you have less than 10 rows/columns it could be `\a` with two arguments `1` and `2` but `\a` is a pre-defined commands in the latex format so it's just a very hard syntax to achieve (which isn't the main point of your question)

Comment: in your suggested output you only seem to be using a row at a time, in order, in which case it appears there should be no need to read in the entire data and define coordinate access macros, just typeset each row as you read it in, that is more the tex way.

Comment: `textmerg` can probably do this, although it is not as bright and shiny as `datatool` et al.

Comment: If you only want to iterate over a csv file try `csvsimple`. It can also produce tables.